# Disable Encode.pm's Warnings

Tags: perl, encoding

I'm using Perl's Encode.pm module, downloaded directly from CPAN (I have updated to the latest version, 2.84, and it is running on Perl 5.10.1 on RHEL). As I use it, it issues warnings about lines 111, 115, and 172 of Encode.pm that look like this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $name in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib64/perl5/Encode.pm line 186.
```

This is rather frustrating, since the warning seems to be about something in Encode.pm rather than my code and I would really like to only see warnings from my code. I do not have the "-w" flag on, but Encode.pm has `use warnings` enabled inside of itself. Is there a way to hide the module's warnings or otherwise fix this situation without having to fork Encode.pm?

I know that muting warnings may, in some ways, be a bad idea, but the overwhelming number of warnings from Encode.pm makes it hard for me to spot the warnings being generated by my own code as I seek to debug it. It is also needlessly messy in the web server logs.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/source/DANKOGAI/Encode-2.84/Encode.pm#L186
There is only a warning if you are using the module wrong. Muting warnings is a bad idea in this case, too.

Comment: I would recommend that you post a minimal example that issues the warning. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6):

Looking up the line referenced in the error message you copied in the question (https://metacpan.org/source/DANKOGAI/Encode-2.84/Encode.pm#L186), we find that `$name` comes directly from the parameters provided to the `decode` function.  If that warning is emitted, it is a direct result of your code calling `decode` incorrectly.

According to Encode's documentation, the correct usage of `decode` is of the form `$string = decode(ENCODING, OCTETS[, CHECK])`, with the concrete example given as `$string = decode("iso-8859-1", $octets);`.  Going back to the source, the first parameter goes into `$name` - it's the name of the encoding used by `$octets`.

The warning, therefore, is telling you about a serious problem in your code - you can't reasonably expect to get meaningful results by attempting to decode a value without specifying its encoding.  You need to fix this very real problem in your code, not just silence the warnings that result from it.  If you need help to fix your calls to `decode`, then please update your question to add a small, runnable script which produces the warning and we can help you to clean it up.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! You were correct. I located the problem and noted it, below.

Answer (score 0):

I finally located the problem. In my code, I take a block of text and detect the encoding it uses:

```
my $encoding_name = Encode::Detect::Detector::detect($hdata);
```

However, some of the text is plain text and Detector doesn't return an encoding name on those blocks. This blank encoding name gets passed on to the `decode` function, causing it to give the warning I reported. To avoid that, I simply started checking to make sure I had an `$encoding_name` before running decode:

```
if ($encoding_name) {
    $hdata = decode($encoding_name, $hdata); 
}
```